# Remove Category Description IF the category is filtered

Tags: catalog, magento2.4.6

Magento 2.4.6

I need to remove the category description from the category page **IF** one of the filters is used.

Ideally, it will be removed from the HTML, but as this is a usability issue more than SEO, hiding it with CSS or JS would be acceptable if that is the only way.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this requirement, you can utilize the `isEnabled` method in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag`. This class checks whether the filter is enabled:

```
public function isEnabled($layer, array $filters = [])
{
    return $this->canShowOptions($filters) || count($layer->getState()->getFilters());
}
```

You can use this logic in a view model class to determine whether the page is filtered. Then call it from the `phtml` template file to determine whether to display the category description.

Since the page builder module (Magento_PageBuilder) overrides the category description template in the `page_layout` directory and wrapped the `referenceBlock` by `referenceContainer`, you must do the same to override this template.
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/**page_layout**/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="category.view.container">
            <referenceBlock name="category.description" template="VendorName_ModuleName::catalog/category/view/description.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="is_category_filtered" xsi:type="object">VendorName\ModuleName\ViewModel\IsCategoryFiltered</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/ViewModel/IsCategoryFiltered.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\ViewModel;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class IsCategoryFiltered implements ArgumentInterface
{
    private Layer $catalogLayer;

    public function __construct(private Resolver $layerResolver)
    {
        $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
    }

    /**
     * Check whether the category page is filtered
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isFiltered(): bool
    {
        return count($this->catalogLayer->getState()->getFilters()) > 0;
    }
}
```

Finally, copy the `phtml` template from the page builder module (vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/frontend/templates/catalog/category/view/description.phtml) to your module and add a condition to determine whether to display the category description:
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/catalog/category/view/description.phtml

```
<?php
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate.FoundHelper

/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View $block
 * @var \VendorName\ModuleName\ViewModel\IsCategoryFiltered $isCategoryFilteredViewModel
 */
$isCategoryFilteredViewModel = $block->getData('is_category_filtered');
?>
<?php if (!$isCategoryFilteredViewModel->isFiltered()): ?>
    // The original code from the Magento_PageBuilder module
    <?php if ($description = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()):?>
    //...
    <?php endif; ?>
    // End the original code from the Magento_PageBuilder module
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Tu_Van. This worked like a charm.

Only things missing were a `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/registration.php` file and a `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/module.xml` file.

It also gives me scope to add some dynamic content where the description would be. Excellent answer. Thanks.

Comment: @myshadowself It’s my pleasure! Yep, these files are required files for a Magento module so I assumed you guys knew that.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the category description from the category page when a filter is used in Magento 2.4.6 follow below steps:

- Override the template file:
  In your custom theme, create the necessary directories to override the template file. Create the following directory structure (if page-builder is enable):

  **`app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_PageBuilder/templates/catalog/category/view/description.phtml`**
- Otherwise, override (page-builder is disable), **`app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/description.phtml`**
- And make changes in **`description.phtml`** with the below code,

---

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$layerResolver = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver');
$layer = $layerResolver->get();
$filters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
if (empty($filters)) :
?>
   //defualt category description code...
<?php endif; ?>
```

**NOTE:** Inject dependency in your PHP file and remove objectManager from the above phtml file.